# C# MVC String Format Zero Values

Tags: c#, string, format

I currently use this to format my numbers.

```
@string.Format("£{0:#,###,###.##}", 1000) outputs £1,000
```

However when I enter a zero value it does this:

```
@string.Format("£{0:#,###,###.##}", 0.0) outputs £
```

How do i make this output even when i enter zero values? e.g £0.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` character means "only use a digit when you need to".

I suspect you want:

```
@string.Format("£{0:#,###,##0.##}", value)
```

However, it would *generally* be a better idea just to use:

```
@string.Format("{0:c}", value)
```

... and let the .NET framework do the right thing.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize the {0:c} existed but i do now!

Answer (score 0):

The first 0 is the placeholder, means the first parameter. 00 is an actual format.

For example it could be like this:

```
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("£{0:#,###,##0.##}", 0));
```